# How to install OpenGL libraries for Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, opengl

I think I should have a folder for OpenGL headers under "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include", but there isn't one there.

How would I go about adding it? From the Visual Studio installer CD, I've tried "Add or Remove Features", which doesn't give me many options. Just Webtools, VB, C# and C++, and having C++ and C# checked when running it didn't help. I've also tried "Repair/Reinstall", which didn't have any options and didn't help.

So how do I install the OpenGL libraries? I'm pretty sure there should be a "gl" folder under include, and I'd thought it would come from the Visual Studio installer. If at all possible, I'd like to avoid having to entirely uninstall and reinstall Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the OpenGL files. They were installed as a part of the Microsoft Windows SDK, and for Windows 7 64bit can be found under:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Include\gl

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio add the directory to: Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->VC++ Directories.

Comment: If the problem were that I could find it on my file system, but Visual Studio wouldn't find it, this would be the correct answer. However, the real problem is that I didn't know what directory to add.

Comment: Deprecated in VS2013.